# MongoDB TTL but to do other stuff

Tags: mongodb, database-trigger, ttl

I have a requirement that when a date attribute field is passed, that we would like to trigger two things:

1. to move the record to be deleted to another table.
2. to call a function to do other actions.

I understand TTL is only to delete a record when the date field is tripped. Can I hook extra logic to it?

Thanks!

Comment: basically #2, is all update or insert database operations.

Comment: Can you show us an example?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the requirements there could be quite a few ways to do this.

One way is to execute a script periodically, and run a query to filter documents that have passed certain date value. For each of the documents, perform a document migration to another table and extra actions.

Alternatively is to use [MongoDB Change Streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/). The trick however, is that [delete events](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/change-events/#delete-event) from change stream do not return the document itself (because it's already been deleted).

Instead if you were to update a field for documents that have passed certain date value you could listen for the [update events](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/change-events/#update-event). For example, sets a field value to `expired:true`.

Worth mentioning that if you're going down the route of change streams update events, you could utilise [MongoDB Stitch Triggers](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/mongodb/triggers/) (relying on change streams). [MongoDB Stitch](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/) database triggers allow you to automatically execute [Stitch functions](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/functions/) in response to changes in your MongoDB database.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest write a function and call it via scheduler. That will be the better option to do it.

Comment: What about using the oplog after TTL deletes the record? Can we use logic to check the oplog entry to insert records in another table?

Is reading oplog reliable?